# Way to Alt-Tab through all applications in Virtual and Host PC

Tags: virtual-pc

I am using VirtualPc 2007 more and more, the one annoyance is "Alt-Tab".

What I want is to be able to use alt-tab to iterate through all of the applications in the host pc and virtual(s) as if they were one long list. Is there a setting or program to do this?

Comment: Do you mean alt-tab through all the programs running *within* the Virtual PC window (I think this is called the "Guest")? So, if you were running FireFox, IE and Notepad within the Virtual PC window and wanted to alt-tab between them.  (This is what *I* want to be able to do)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  If the VPC is in full screen mode, alt+tab works only within the context of the VPC.  If the VPC Screen is not focused, you will get the collection of applications that are in the Host (including the instance of VPC)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, no.  This is possible in Parallels on the Mac, in what they call "Coherence" mode.  But Virtual PC does not support that kind of integration.

Answer (score 1):

No. If the VPC is in full screen mode, alt+tab works only within the context of the VPC. However, you may find the "Host key+DOWN ARROW" shortcut useful. This minimizes the virtual machine and allows you to alt-tab on the host again.